# Convert CSV Single Column with multiple rows to single row using powershell

Tags: powershell, csv

Convert CSV Single Column with multiple rows to single row using powershell.

INPUT

```
00:00:05:00
00:00:10:00
00:00:15:00
```

OUTPUT

```
00:00:05:00,00:00:10:00,00:00:15:00
```

Answer (score 1):

You really should put a bit more effort in researching learning before asking :-(
This is quite trivial.

```
> cat input.csv
00:00:05:00
00:00:10:00
00:00:15:00

> $csv = import-csv .\input.csv -header data
> $csv.data -join(',')
00:00:05:00,00:00:10:00,00:00:15:00

> "$($csv.data)" -replace ' ',','
00:00:05:00,00:00:10:00,00:00:15:00

> (gc .\input.csv) -join(',')
00:00:05:00,00:00:10:00,00:00:15:00
```

To show only some possible ways.

Comment: Million Thanks LotPings.I did research, but couldn't find any, maybe used a wrong keyword